# Error installing pyodbc via pip for Python 3.9 on Windows

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm a newbie here. I'm trying to install **pyodbc** by pip but getting below error.

[image]
Any idea why it may happen?

Thanks

Comment: Try to install the wheel. ```pip wheel``` before installing pyodbc

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc has not yet released Windows wheels for Python 3.9. In the meantime you can download a Python 3.9 wheel from

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)

For the latest information on this issue see

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/833

Answer (score 0):

It's written in open text

> "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required"

. On PyPI website under pyodbc it reads

> ".....pyodbc contains C++ extensions so you will need a suitable C++
> compiler on your computer to install pyodbc, for all operating
> systems."

I personally have installed Microsoft Visual 2015 C++ Redistributable. It weighs 23,5 Mb.